# how to get the numbers in columns of a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below df, and I'd like to take only the numbers (with their signs) of the columns.
The original df is:

```
               0     1       2          3      4          5  
0      ddd [ -03  62.0    16 ]   nal [  01 -49.0    00149 ]   
1      ddd [ -04  61.0    15 ]   nal [  00 -32.0    00209 ]
```

and I'd like to get the below:

```
         0     1     2   3      4        5  
0      -03  62.0    16   01 -49.0    00149   
1      -04  61.0    15   00 -32.0    00209
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for all columns of DatFrame wit extract integers of floats with `-` values:

```
df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.extract(r'([-]?\d+\.*\d*)', expand=False))
print (df)
     0     1   2   3      4      5
0  -03  62.0  16  01  -49.0  00149
1  -04  61.0  15  00  -32.0  00209
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['Tres3', 'Acht8', 'SevenTwo72']})
df['Data'] = df['Data'].map(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]))`

#Returns: 
#3
#8
#72
```